# Is each instrument on ISRO MOM independently in 24x7 contact with Earth?

Tags: mars, communication, isro, mars-orbiter-mission

The [ISRO](http://www.isro.org) [Mars Orbiter Mission](http://www.isro.org/mars/payload.aspx) web-site writes to say

> Mars Orbiter Mission carries five scientific payloads to observe Martian surface, atmosphere and exosphere extending up to 80,000 km for a detailed understanding of the evolution of that planet, especially the related geologic and the possible biogenic processes on that interesting planet. These payloads consist of a camera, two spectrometers, a radiometer and a photometer.

The same web-site goes on to provide a brief of each of these instruments.

The question then that comes to mind is -

Does the space-craft have a dedicated channel for each instrument to convey it's data? **OR**
Is the data from each instrument queued before dispatch?

I'm also curious to know what is the total bandwidth required/utilized by MOM for all 5 instruments.

Comment: It's a bit odd how you describe possible downlink redundancy. It's not how it's usually done and data products from individual experiments are simply added to the same downlink queue, then the comms subsystem decides how to transmit them. You can usually prioritize this queue to favor particular experiments tho, if that's needed, say due to bandwidth constraints. Also related: [Mars Orbiter Mission activates all science instruments as NASA, ISRO form joint Mars working group](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2014/10010914-mars-orbiter-mission.html)

Comment: There is some on-board storage (either at the output from each instrument, or at the input to the transmission queue) then ... wonder [how much the storage for each instrument is](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/what-will-mom-do-when-earth-isnt-looking?lq=1)