# What will MOM do when Earth isn't looking?

Tags: mars, communication, isro, data-storage, mars-orbiter-mission

A quick follow-up to [Is each instrument on ISRO MOM independently in 24x7 contact with Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/is-each-instrument-on-isro-mom-independently-in-24x7-contact-with-earth)

Every 26 months Sol interposes to occult Earth from the gaze of the Warlord. The last time this occurred was in June-July 2014. This occultation is not only visual, but applies to perhaps all frequencies in the E/M spectrum. Ergo, communication between Earth/Mars just can not happen.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization_of_Mars#Communication) writes to say

> In reality most missions at Mars have had communications blackout periods of the order of a month.[[38]](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1196/annals.1370.007/abstract)

Although the MOM has a planned life far shorter than the 26-month blackout frequency, one can not help wondering

- What is the data storage capability for each instrument aboard MOM?
- **IF** MOM was to be extended into the next comm.blackout period, would the onboard instruments be put on standby for that duration?

Comment: Maybe the title can be updated - possibly to past tense? It's still an interesting question and needs a good answer.